# Invalid index scalar variable for a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I tried to make a for loop but I am so far without any success. The first iteration executes perfectly, but afterwards it gives the error:

> IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

for the line `Ylog=[(data1.Z>a[i])&(data1.Z<a[i+1])]`

I don't know where it's coming from...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

base=pd.read_csv('pont du gard.csv',sep=';',index_col=0)
data1=pd.read_csv('P1.csv',sep=';',index_col=0)

P1=np.sqrt((base.X['Base']-data1.X)**2+(base.Y['Base']-data1.Y)**2)

a=np.array([77,86.6,95,115,125])
for i in range(5):
    Xlog=[(P1)]
    Ylog=[(data1.Z>a[i])&(data1.Z<a[i+1])]
    logique=np.logical_and(Xlog,Ylog).flatten()
    x=P1[logique]
    z=data1.Z[logique]
    a, b, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,z)
    plt.plot(x,a*x+b)
    print('Pendage P1:',np.arctan(a1)*180/np.pi,'°')
    print('Erreur de :', 1-np.absolute(r_value))
```

Comment: When `i` is 4, then `a[i+1]` will be out of index. However it is not what the error is saying.

Comment: Yes, I changed `in range(5)` to `in range(4)` but still this error... Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the loop you redefine the variable `a` when you do

`a, b, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,z)`.

Therefore from the second iteration `a` is not an array but a scalar, hence you cannot index it, and such error is raised.